# Licensing/Securing an asp .net web application

Tags: asp.net

Basically I have an asp.net application which is installed on clients servers to work alongside an existing desktop application.  What can I do to stop a client copying the files and installing somewhere else and running it so they can't stop paying but continue to use the system?

Answer (score 1):

The only 100% way I know that you can use is to have a call to some webservice you control to validate every time the application starts or in any other event you want. Still, clients could decompile it and patch it to remove the check although this is unlikely.

However, I wouldn't worry about validating this as much as I would if I had to have this kind of lock in place. If you believe your clients are doing this they are not good clients to start working with.